# How do you place down sugar canes on mc pe?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Please tell me how to do this because my sister will go CRAZY because she loves them.

Answer (score -1):

Place the sugar cane on sand or grass right next to water

Comment: Hi @ZMangames - Welcome to Arqade! Whilst this answer is technically correct, It would help if you flesh your answers out a little more, and be more specific in your wording. For example, does flowing water also work, or can you only place next to still-water blocks? Is there a reason why it only works on grass or sand? What about dirt blocks? Is there any difference to how this works in Minecraft PE vs the original game? If you did this, and perhaps provide a link to a canonical source, such as the Minecraft Wiki, you'll find that you'll get a more positive reception on your answers :)